# Android: Passing back user input from DialogFragment results in NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

so i looked at the Android tutorial for Dialogs [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).
And Decided to make a custom Dialog to ask a user for a host, username and password to connect to. I dont want to connect to the host within the Dialog Class so i need to pass the strings back to the main activity. I tried to to that with an Interface just like in the tutorial but when i want to handle the event in the main activity accessing the EditText i get a NullPointerException. Im sure there is an easy workaround or Im making some other stupid mistake. Please help!

Dialog Class:

```
public class ConnectionDialog extends DialogFragment {

public interface NoticeDialogListener {
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog);
    public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);
}

// Use this instance of the interface to deliver action events
NoticeDialogListener mListener;

// Override the Fragment.onAttach() method to instantiate the NoticeDialogListener
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    // Verify that the host activity implements the callback interface
    try {
        // Instantiate the NoticeDialogListener so we can send events to the host
        mListener = (NoticeDialogListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        // The activity doesn't implement the interface, throw exception
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement NoticeDialogListener");
    }
}


@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Get the layout inflater
    final LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.connection_dialog, null))
            // Add action buttons
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.connect, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(ConnectionDialog.this);
                    // sign in the user ...
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.abort, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    mListener.onDialogNegativeClick(ConnectionDialog.this);
                    //LoginDialogFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
                }
            });
    return builder.create();

}
}
```

And Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ConnectionDialog.NoticeDialogListener {

public void showConnectionDialog() {
    // Create an instance of the dialog fragment and show it
    DialogFragment dialog = new ConnectionDialog();
    dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "Connection Dialog");
}

public void toast(String message){
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, duration);
    toast.show();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

@Override
public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
    EditText editHost = (EditText)dialog.getView().findViewById(R.id.dialog_host);
    EditText editUser = (EditText)dialog.getView().findViewById(R.id.dialog_user);
    EditText editPassword = (EditText)dialog.getView().findViewById(R.id.dialog_password);
    String host = editHost.getText().toString();
    String user = editUser.getText().toString();
    String password = editPassword.getText().toString();

    dialog.dismiss();
}

@Override
public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
    toast("cancled");
    dialog.dismiss();
    // User touched the dialog's negative button
}
public void connect(View view){
    showConnectionDialog();
}
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Edit:

NullPointerException

```
04-12 18:52:00.278 5216-5216/com.example.josias.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.example.josias.myapplication, PID: 5216
                                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                at com.example.josias.myapplication.MainActivity.onDialogPositiveClick(MainActivity.java:44)
                                                                                at com.example.josias.myapplication.ConnectionDialog$2.onClick(ConnectionDialog.java:54)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:153)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: On a different note: Why don't you pass `String` values through `interface` instead of dialog?

Comment: You have to `show()` a dialog before you use `findViewById` on it, otherwise, you will get `null`

Comment: @cricket_007
i do. i just forgot to include it in the code aboce. now its there. the method connect() is executed by pressing a button

Comment: @RohitArya
i thought about that but then i could not access the EditText from within the onClick method. i think its because the onClick method is within the setPositiveButton which is run before the builder is acutally created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch out your interfaces to pass the String values instead of passing along the entire dialog.

To get you started, do something like this

```
public interface NoticeDialogListener {
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(String host, String user, String pass);
    public void onDialogNegativeClick();
}
```

```
final LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
// Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
// Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.connection_dialog, null);

final EditText editHost = (EditText)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_host);
final EditText editUser = (EditText)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_user);
final EditText editPassword = (EditText)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_password);

builder.setView(dialogView)
        // Add action buttons
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.connect, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                String host = editHost.getText().toString();
                String user = editUser.getText().toString();
                String pass = editPassword.getText().toString();

                mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(host, user, pass);
            }
        })
        // set null to dismiss dialog
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.abort, null);
return builder.create();
```

Comment: Thats exactly what i was looking for. Thanks! If i wanted to make it more complicated i could still pass the entire dialogView, right?

Comment: You could, but it's a good habit to only pass around the variables you actually need. If you need complicated, then perhaps make some class to hold all the data from the dialog and use that instead of adding on many parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Yes You can.
Your interface will look like this,

```
public interface NoticeDialogListener {
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog);
}
```

Pass DialogFragment instance like this to the interface, in positive button onClick () method.

```
.setPositiveButton(R.string.add, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    noticeDialogListener.onDialogPositiveClick(NoticeDialog.this);
                }
            })
```

Next in your MainActivity - you can have every field of DialogFragment that you have displayed as forms. In interface method that you will override in MainActivity, define like this,

```
@Override
public void onSaveButtonClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
 ......

    EditText field1= (EditText) dialog.getDialog().findViewById(R.id.field1);
    EditText field2= (EditText) dialog.getDialog().findViewById(R.id.field2);
....
}
```

Then you can get the Text and work as per your requirement. For more information you can refre this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a0T--DfR48A Here everything is explained well...

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
dialog.getDialog()
```

instead of:

```
dialog.getView()
```

Comment: what this kind of nonsense answer.